# Why ReentrantLock does not show its unfairness in this demo code?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying to write a code that shows the unfairness of ReentrantLock (when ctor is passed fair=false). To my surprise, ReentrantLock was perfectly fair.

My test has the following logic: spawn 20 threads who have an "id" going from 0 to 19. All threads share a ReentrantLock. Then, in chronological order:

- Thread 0 locks the lock.
- Thread 1 to 19 block on lock(), in order 1, then 2, then 3, .. , then 19
- Thread 0 unlocks the lock. This is the first test of fairness, if the lock is fair, thread 1 should get it thereafter
- When thread 1 has the lock, he releases it too. Second test of fairness: thread 2 should now get it.
- etc

I was expecting that sometimes, a thread gets the lock before another one that was actually waiting for longer. But it never happens

The code:

```
package jma.test;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class ThreadTest extends Thread {
    private final int id;
    private final int totalNbThreads;
    private final ReentrantLock lock1;
    private final LinkedList<Integer> checkOrder;

    ThreadTest(int id, int totalNbThreads, ReentrantLock lock, LinkedList<Integer> checkOrder) {
        this.id = id;
        this.totalNbThreads = totalNbThreads;
        this.lock1 = lock;
        this.checkOrder = checkOrder;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // This if is to force threads to get to lock() call below in order of their ids.
            // Thread 0 should call lock() first, then threads 1, 2, 3, 4 ...
            if (this.id == 1) {
                while (!lock1.isLocked()) {
                    // wait for thread 0 to lock it
                }
            } else if (this.id > 1) {
                while (lock1.getQueueLength() != (this.id - 1)) {
                    // íf we are thread n, we wait for thread 1 to n-1 to enter the wait queue.
                }
            }

            lock1.lock();
            if (this.id == 0) {
                while (lock1.getQueueLength() !=  (totalNbThreads - 1)) {
                    // Wait for all other threads to bloc on lock1.lock() before releasing lock
                }
            }
            checkOrder.add(this.id);
        } finally {
            lock1.unlock();
        }

    }
}

public class Main {
    private static final int NB_THREADS = 20; // at least 2

    // change the boolean to switch between fair or not-fair lock
    private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(false);

    private static boolean isLockFair() {
        Queue<Thread> allThreads = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Integer> checkOrder = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int id=0; id < NB_THREADS; id++) {
            allThreads.add(new ThreadTest(id, NB_THREADS, lock, checkOrder));
        }

        for (Thread t : allThreads) {
            t.start();
        }

        for (Thread t : allThreads) {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        int previous = -1;
        for (int i : checkOrder) {
            if (i != previous + 1) {
                System.out.println("not fair: " + i + " got the lock after " + previous);
                return false;
            }
            previous = i;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ctrUnfair = 0;
        int nbTest = 10000;

        for (int i=0; i<nbTest; i++) {
            if (!isLockFair())
                ctrUnfair++;
        }

        System.out.println("unfairness: " + ctrUnfair + "/" + nbTest);
    }
}
```

I assume that, because the thread releasing the lock does not try to get it again, when unlock is called there is no concurrency between the running thread and the blocked threads, so the thread that will get the lock necessarily comes from the wait queue, and the implementation of the wait queue is probably a FIFO. Is it the explanation ?

Comment: You aren't measuring the fairness of the lock because your threads don't actually wait for the lock. They actually "wait" in endless loops that burn the CPU.

Comment: Sorry i don't get you. The loops are only here so that i know the order in which the threads get the lock or start to wait for the lock. The fairness test begin after. When n threads are blocked on lock(), isn't it measuring fairness to check if the thread that get the lock is the one waiting in lock() for the longest time ?

Comment: No. Because the threads have all used up their timeslices spinning. So you're measuring the scheduler, not the lock. Change the spinning to sensible synchronization.

Comment: When a thread calls lock.unlock(), it wakes up all the threads that have been put to sleep on lock() ? (meaning they are moved into the run queue of the scheduler). And those threads will all compete to get the lock ? I thought that unlock() was choosing a thread to wake up from the queue of threads waiting on the lock.

Comment: If `unlock()` doesn't choose which thread to wake up, then clearly the scheduler is choosing. If `unlock()` does choose which thread to wake up, then it has to replicate the scheduler's logic (for example, respecting priorities and so on). So either way, the result is the same -- the scheduler's rules are followed. As the docs say, "*Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are not progressing and not currently holding the lock.*"

Comment: I don't see why `unlock` would have to replicate scheduler's logic. In particular, if the lock is constructed as a fair lock, `unlock` should choose the thread that has waited for the longest time after the lock, no matter the CPU it has already used. This is a different logic than the scheduler's one. And `unlock` only has to choose between the treads waiting for the lock, unlike the scheduler.

Comment: I think the problem boils down to : do `unlock` wakes up every thread waiting for the lock and let the scheduler favorite one (that will hence get the lock), or does it choose a thread and wakes only that one.

Comment: That's the wrong question though, since the fact that `unlock` may or may not let the scheduler decide which thread to run is an implementation detail that can't affect the actual guaranteed semantics of the lock.

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting that sometimes, a thread gets the lock before another one that was actually waiting for longer. But it never happens

In my understanding,this happens in the case below.

> 1.Thread a call **unlock**,after execute **tryRelease** but before **unparkSuccessor**,thread scheduling happens,Thread b start to execute.
>
> 2.Thread b call **lock**,if it is a none fair lock,it will call **compareAndSetState** and will success,you see though other threads waiting for the lock,but thread b got it,but if it is a fair lock,it will test if current thread is the first thread waiting for the lock ,see **hasQueuedPredecessors**.

All these comes from the source code [AQS](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java) and [ReentrantLock](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java).

Back to your code,before thread 0 can **unlock**,all other threads are in the waiting queue,so different with the case above.Hope this helps and if I am wrong,please let me know.